# File’s shift encryption and decryption - Code isn't working properly

Tags: c

My code is working when I am running it in codeblocks but when I am trying to open the .exe file of it, its not working there properly. Would some one help please ?

I am a beginner learner of programming. This is the first code I am working on. A simple caesar cipher in c. I took help from web to write the code. Its running well when I am running it in codeblocks but its not working when I am running the .exe file. It stops after I input the key. I don't know what to do now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCHAR 1000

int main()
{
  int i, x, key;
  FILE *fptr;
  char str[MAXCHAR], ch, filename[MAXCHAR];

  printf("\nPlease enter a File Name: ");
  scanf("%s", &filename);
  fptr = fopen(filename, "r+");
  if (fptr == NULL){
    printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
  }
  while (fgets(str,MAXCHAR, fptr) != NULL);
  printf("\nPlease choose following options:\n");
  printf("1 = Encrypt the string.\n");
  printf("2 = Decrypt the string.\n");
  scanf("%d", &x);
  printf("Enter key: ");
  scanf("%d", &key);
  switch(x)
  {
  case 1:
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
      ch = str[i];

      if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
        ch = ch + key;

        if(ch > 'z'){
          ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
        }

        str[i] = ch;
      }
      else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
        ch = ch + key;

        if(ch > 'Z'){
          ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
        }

        str[i] = ch;
      }
    }
    printf("Encrypted string: %s\n", str);
    break;

  case 2:

    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
      ch = str[i];

      if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
        ch = ch - key;

        if(ch < 'a'){
          ch = ch + 'z' - 'a' + 1;
        }

        str[i] = ch;
      }
      else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
        ch = ch - key;

        if(ch < 'A'){
          ch = ch + 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
        }

        str[i] = ch;
      }
    }
    printf("Decrypted string: %s\n", str);
    break;

  default:
    printf("\nError\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is the requirement I was trying to fill up .

> Implementation:
>
> 1. File encryption
> 2. File decryption
>
> Note:
>
> Read the contents(plain text) from a file (only English letter allowed) as characters, in terms of the KEY (input from keyboard by user ) shift the corresponding character(get cipher text), and do the reverse operation when decrypting the file.
>
> For example:
>
> Assume the plain text is “abcdef”, KEY is 5, then every single letter in the plain text will shift right by 5 positions according to the alphabet( the following letter after z is a), get the cipher text (garbled)“fghijkl”.
>
> Now decrypt the cipher text: fghijkl, KEY is 5, and then every single letter in the cipher text will be shift left by 5 positions according to the alphabet( the following letter after a is z), get the original text “abcdef”.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with the code you mentioned. Firstly this

```
scanf("%s", &filename); /* & is not needed */
```

is wrong, compiler could warned you like

> error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2
>   has type ‘char (*)[1000]’ [-Werror=format=]

if you had compile your code with flags like `-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror`. Remove `&` as `filename` is char array and array name itself address, correct one is

```
scanf("%s", filename);
```

secondly, here

```
while (fgets(str,MAXCHAR, fptr) != NULL); /* dummy loop */
```

semicolon `;` at the end of `while` is intentional or typo ? as due to `;` when loop fails `str` contains `NULL`. You may want like

```
while (fgets(str,MAXCHAR, fptr) != NULL) { /* some code */ }
```

Also `fgets()` stores the new line at the end of buffer, you might want to remove that trailing `\n`. For e.g

```
while(fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fptr) != NULL) {
        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0; /* remove the trailing \n */
        /* some code */
 }
```

Finally, here

```
if (fptr == NULL){
    printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
  }
```

`fopen()` handling is not correct as if file doesn't exist or `fopen()` failed it simply print the message and proceed further & do the operation with `fptr` which it shouldn't, use `return 0` or `exit(0)`. For e.g

```
if (fptr == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"Could not open file %s",filename);
    return 0; /* this is must */
}
```

Sample code:

```
#define MAXCHAR 1000
int main(void) {
        int i, x, key;
        FILE *fptr;
        char str[MAXCHAR], ch, filename[MAXCHAR]/* I don't think filename will be that much big, use accordingly */;
        printf("\nPlease enter a File Name: ");
        scanf("%s", &filename); /* & is not required as filename itself address */
        fptr = fopen(filename, "r+");
        if (fptr == NULL){
                printf("Could not open file %s",filename);
                return 0; /* add this else it proceeed further */
        }
        while (fgets(str,MAXCHAR, fptr) != NULL) { /* remove semicolon, read each line from file, store into str and do the operation with str  */
                printf("\nPlease choose following options:\n");
                printf("1 = Encrypt the string.\n");
                printf("2 = Decrypt the string.\n");
                scanf("%d", &x);
                printf("Enter key: ");
                scanf("%d", &key);
                switch(x) {
                        case 1:
                                for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
                                        ch = str[i];

                                        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                                                ch = ch + key;
                                                if(ch > 'z'){
                                                        ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
                                                }

                                                str[i] = ch;
                                        }
                                        else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                                                ch = ch + key;
                                                if(ch > 'Z'){
                                                        ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
                                                }

                                                str[i] = ch;
                                        }
                                }
                                printf("Encrypted string: %s\n", str);
                                break;
                        case 2:
                                for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){
                                        ch = str[i];
                                        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                                                ch = ch - key;
                                                if(ch < 'a'){
                                                        ch = ch + 'z' - 'a' + 1;
                                                }

                                                str[i] = ch;
                                        }
                                        else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                                                ch = ch - key;

                                                if(ch < 'A'){
                                                        ch = ch + 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
                                                }

                                                str[i] = ch;
                                        }
                                }
                                printf("Decrypted string: %s\n", str);
                                break;

                        default:
                                printf("\nError\n");

                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I am sorry it might be very silly mistake but I am really very new to programming. I changed the the mistake as you mentioned but still the same result. When I open the .exe file it works till I input the key. When I press enter to input the key, it stops but it runs through the end in IDE.

Comment: try `rb` mode in `fopen()` as its binary file.

Comment: I changed it but same result. Would you please try to run the code ?